# Org Mode - Is there a way to reverse org-list-make-subtree?

Tags: org-mode, list

By using `org-list-make-subtree` (`C-c C-*`) you turn an Org List into a sub tree:

```
- Item 1
 - Item 2
  - Item 3
```

would turn into

```
* Item 1
** Item 2
*** Item 3
```

But is there a built in function (like `org-subtree-make-list`)to reverse this operation or would you need to do it by hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `org-ctrl-c-minus` (bound to `C-c -` by default) turns a region of lines into a list. You need to mark the lines you want to change first, but it works with the headlines in your example as well.

Here's a defun you might use to mark the subtree and then change it to a list:

```
(defun org-subtree-make-list ()
  (interactive)
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (org-ctrl-c-minus))
```